# (C++/CLI) Nested structure's property value is not changing in the Propertygrid

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Firstly i would like to inform that I am quite new to C++/CLI programming and apologize if my question seems to be very basic. I have been searching the web for a solution the whole day but was unsuccessful.

I have a value struct which has another value struct as one of its data members. All the properties are displayed on the Propertygrid and are editable. But when I try to modify the property of the nested struct, the new value is not retained and it reverts back to 0 immediately. Why is this happening and how do I retain the value entered for the nested struct?

NOTE: I tried to comment out void set(nestedStruct value){ temp = value; } but still face the same issue.

```
[TypeConverter(ExpandableObjectConverter::typeid)]
public value struct nestedStruct
{
    int z;
    property int Z
    {
        int get()           { return z; }
        void set(int value) { z = value; }
    };
};

public value struct parentStruct
{
    int x;
    property int X
    {
        int get()           { return x; }
        void set(int value) { x = value; }
    };

    int y;
    property int Y
    {
        int get()           { return y; }
        void set(int value) { y = value; }
    };

    nestedStruct temp;
    property nestedStruct Temp
    {
        nestedStruct get()          { return temp; }
        void set(nestedStruct value){ temp = value; }
    };
};
```

Assigning to property grid:

```
parentStruct testStruct;
propertyGrid1->SelectedObject = testStruct;
propertyGrid1->ExpandAllGridItems();
```

Comment: Standard behavior of a value type.  Make it a class to trivially solve your problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks. It solves the problem but I am using the value struct as part of a larger solution for many other reasons. So its necessary for me to use the value struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post under C# tag very helpful to solve the problem:

[C# PropertyGrid: Changing properties not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2083176/1003169)

I needed to override only the CanConvertFrom() from ExpandableObjectConverter.

```
public ref class MyExpandableObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
public:
    virtual bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext^ context, Type^ sourceType) override
    {
        if (sourceType == String::typeid) 
            return true;
        else 
            return ExpandableObjectConverter::CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
};
```

and use the new type converter:

```
[TypeConverter(MyExpandableObjectConverter::typeid)]
public value struct nestedStruct
{
    int z;

    property int Z
    {
        int get()           { return z; }
        void set(int value) { z = value; }
    };
};
```